# Отправка SMS с помощью модема

Tags: sms

Дано:

1. Linux машина.
2. USB модем Huawei (модель не важна - с тем же успехом может быть любой другой).
3. Модем подключен как несколько USB COM-портов (ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2)

Прошу помочь реализовать алгоритм отправки СМС - явно нужно использовать АТ-команды... Какие? В каком порядке?

Comment: Не ответ, но может стоит готовые сервисы использовать? И дешевле будет, и универсальнее + кабинет, статистика и все такое.

Comment: необходимо уточнить вопрос: планируются ли длинные смс(состоящие из нескольких частей), в какой кодировке будет отправляться текс(ASCII || UTF), потому что исходя из ответов на эти вопросы алгоритм будет меняться: Используемые команды, кодировка текста

Comment: @VladimirGamalian только хардкор - только самостоятельно.

Comment: @Bald - спасибо, рассмотрим разные варианты. Скорее всего понадобится UTF (кириллица нужна 90%)

Comment: если нужна UTF то тогда необходимо будет формировать PDU пакет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Материал в [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133085/)

Пример:

```
AT+CMGF=1 [Enter]
AT+CMGS=+79261234567 [Enter]
hello habr, this is test message [Ctrl+Z]
```

Для командования модемом рекомендую minicom на время отладки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом уже можно и код написать на любимом языке